# Impossible to update app package

Tags: uwp, windows-8.1-universal, windows-dev-center, microsoft-appstudio

I had an app studio app (windows 8.1) that recently was removed from the store because I failed to update the Age Ratings.  Recently I requested that the app be reactivated in the store so I could submit an updated version with the Age ratings questionnaire filled out.

It was reactivated.  I proceed to update my app in app studio to Windows 10.  I submit the new package in Windows Dev Center, but I keep getting this error.

> A previous submission for this app was released with a Windows Phone
>   8.1 or Windows 8.1 appxbundle. Your Windows 10 submission must also contain an appxbundle

appxbundle doesn't exist for windows 10 apps.  Furthermore I don't have any previous Windows 8.1 appxbundle other than the last original that was published to the store. But in order to update I need to increment the version.  Generating a new Windows 8.1 package from App Studio no longer provides appxbundle.  But rather appupload files.

It impossible to update this app through dev center.   What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Furthermore I don't have any previous Windows 8.1 appxbundle other
>   than the last original that was published to the store.

Please note that once your app is published as appxbundle, it's impossible to go back to non-appxbundle format.

If you're not able to genetate appxbundle in App Studio, you can download source project and open it up using Visual Studio. Then you can follow the **[create an app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package)** to generate appxbundle package for your submission.

[image]

Just select "Always" so that your app name will be _x86_x64_arm_bundle.appxupload format.